# How to truncate date in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, date-arithmetic

I am using below condition to truncate date in postgres

```
to_date(to_char(trunc(appointment_date),'YYYYMMDD')||appointment_end_time,''YYYYMMDDHH24:MI:SS')AS tq
```

How I can use this in postgres ?

Comment: What data type are `appointment_date` and `appointment_end_time`? And what exactly are you trying to do there? Create a `timestamp` from a `date` and a `time` value?

Comment: Appointment date is of timestamp without time zone type and appointment _end_time is of type character varying type ...I want to select those fileds

Comment: Why are you storing a time value in a `varchar` column?  That is a really bad idea.

Answer (score 5):

Strange data typing, sometimes requires strange, looking at least, queries. Try (see [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=36d5f4d8543313b7d003231c6e078972))

```
date_trunc('day',appointment_date) 
       + substr(appoinment_end,12)::interval
```

Answer (score 4):

As your `to_char()` call uses the format `'HH24:MI:SS'` for the "time" column, you can cast that column directly to a `time` value, e.g. using the `::` operator: `appointment_end_time::time`.

To build a new timestamp from the date part of the `appointment_date` and the time value, just add them:

```
appointment_date::date + appointment_end_time::time
```

So first the timestamp is converted to a date (that does not have a time), and then the time value is added to that, which [yields](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html) a `timestamp`.

---

Note that `to_date()` returns a `date` so your code would remove the just added time part again. You would need to use `to_timestamp()` if you really want a timestamp as the result.

---

To answer the question's title "how to truncate date in Postgres?" (which in reality refers to a `timestamp` not a `date`): you can either cast it to a `date` (see above) or you can use `date_trunc()` (not `trunc()`) with a unit to which it should be truncated. However, `date_trunc` returns a `timestamp` **not** a `date` value, so you couldn't add a time to the result.